# What Is The Next Best Ingredient?

Tags: recursion

I am building a program that allows users to optimize their grocery shopping so they can make the most recipes using the fewest ingredients.

One of the features of this program is a function I’m calling the “NEXT BEST INGREDIENT” or NBI.  For example, if you already have salt, oil, and rosemary, what NBI will unlock the most additional recipes?

Let’s say the answer is beef.  If you buy beef, you’ll be able to create more new recipes than if you bought any other ingredient.

After buying beef, what is the NEXT BEST INGREDIENT one should add after that?  And so on.

The feature will allow a user to enter any number of starting ingredients (including zero).  So someone could start with 0, 3, or even 50 ingredients.  What should they add next?

I’m using a database of recipes (about 500K recipes in all) to compile results.

I can map out the individuals steps for writing out a specific algorithm.  But I need help writing a more generic algorithm.

Here’s a specific algorithm:

A user enters in 3 ingredients A, B, and C

1. Isolate all 4-ingredient recipes that use use A+B+C + BLANK.  Note the BLANK with highest frequency.
2. Isolate all 3-ingredient recipes that use A+B + BLANK… A+C + BLANK… B+C + BLANK. Note the BLANK with highest frequency.
3. Isolate all 2-ingredient recipes that use A + BLANK….B + BLANK…C+ BLANK. Note the BLANK with highest frequency.
4. Isolate all 1-ingredient recipes that simply use BLANK. Note the BLANK with highest frequency.
5. Calculate the BLANK with the highest TOTAL frequency.  This is the NEXT BEST INGREDIENT.

But I need a way to write a more generic algorithm for when a user enters N number of ingredients (anything from 0 ingredients to 100).

I can write out the rules in plain English – but my programmer needs a way to write a generic rule using coding logic.

Here it is in plain English.

***When user searches N ingredients (including zero), instantly ignore any recipes that require N+2 ingredients or more.  And then isolate ALL remaining recipes that use ALL, SOME, or NONE of those ingredients such that there is 1 (and only 1) vacant slot for an “unsearched” ingredient.

Tally up the frequency of all “unsearched” ingredients.  Whichever “unsearched” ingredient has the highest frequency becomes the NEXT BEST INGREDIENT.***

The goal is to make this search feature accurate (or as accurate as my database is) and fast.  A few ingredients is easy.  But when looking at 10+ ingredients, it may slow down a bit.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a programming question (which I suspect has been well studied).  It belongs on stackoverflow.se  Storing some index of the database will make it easy, I think.

Comment: Note that the next best ingredient plus the next next best ingredient are not necessarily as good together as a different pair of ingredients which wouldn't both be recommended in a row. For the sake of converting this problem into math, pretend the ingredients are integers and you want to maximize the number of subset products they produce but at the same time minimize the size of the integers.

Comment: thanks guys.  i posted my question on the database section.  cheers.

Comment: Do _you_ have any thoughts? A specific question? This isn't a discussion forum or place to have your work done for your

Answer (score 0):

You have a *set* of ingredients, and each recipe has a *set* of ingredients. Loop through taking the *set difference*, and see which differences contain exactly one ingredient.

Some pseudocode:

```
initialize counts

for each recipe
  ingredients = set_difference(recipe_ingredients, my_ingredients)
  if length(ingredients) == 1
    increment counts[ingredient]

maximum(counts) == next_best_ingredient
```

Getting the `next_best_ingredients` (plural) is trickier, because there could be a #2 and #3 ingredient from above for instance that generates more matches than #1 and #2 combined. I'm not sure how to solve that, but you could repeat the previous loop with the top 10 or so and call it good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, whether this leads to the most efficient implementation, but I'd try the following:
- For each remaining recipe (with at most N+1 ingredients, that connot already be cooked), build the union of your N Ingredient's and the Ingredients of that recipe.
- If there are more than N+1 ingredients in the resulting set, discard the recipe. Otherwise take the new ingredient and increase its counter variable or add new counter variable  for that ingredient.

If you can, you should probably make sure, that your ingredient lists for each recipe are stored sorted in the database. That way the set generation / the detection of more than one mismatch should be very fast.